# R - Add values to data frame matching a certain criteria

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have the following two data frames:

```
d <- data.frame(c1 = c("A","A","B","C","A","C","D","D"))

map <- data.frame(c1 = c("A","B","C","D"), c2 = c(12,14,16,25))
```

How can I add another column called "match" to data frame d that contains corresponding values found in data frame map? So data frame d should look like:

```
A 12
A 12
B 14
C 16
A 12
C 16
D 25
D 25
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using the function called `match`:

```
d$match <- map$c2[match(d$c1,map$c1)]
```

And because of the way these levels are specified, you could also do:

```
d$match <- map$c2[d$c1]
```

But this only works if each row in `match` exactly matches the levels of the `c1` factor in order.